# How do I get past the drones in the sewers?

Tags: batman-arkham-knight

I'm in the sewers, searching for Poison Ivy's second plant. There are three drones I have to disable with the remote hacking device while on foot so I can open a door to let the Batmobile through. However, I can't seem to disable the second drone. It is around a corner and I've died five times trying to find a vantage point.

**How do I disable the drones in the sewer so I can open the door blocking the Batmobile?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to take cover at the corner first, before attempting to hack the drones.  That way you aren't out in the open when trying to hack them.

Just "sneak" to the corner and press your jump button.  Batman will take cover at the corner.  Then from there, you can aim and hack the drone without putting yourself in danger.